# mdadm lost RAID5 after new motherboard and processor

Tags: ubuntu, raid, mdadm, raid-5

I moved my mdadm RAID5 to a different motherboard/processor, same boot drive.

The array is no longer found during a mdadm --assemble --scan

The motherboard was previously running INTEL RAID, so when it booted it up it showed all four drives in the RAID5 as not part of the RAID.

```
root@server:/dev# mdadm --examine /dev/sdc
/dev/sdc:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :   4294967295 sectors at            1 (type ee)
root@server:/dev# mdadm --examine /dev/sdd
/dev/sdd:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :   3907029167 sectors at            1 (type ee)
root@server:/dev# mdadm --examine /dev/sde
/dev/sde:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :   3907029167 sectors at            1 (type ee)
root@server:/dev# mdadm --examine /dev/sdf
/dev/sdf:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :   3907029167 sectors at            1 (type ee)
root@server:/dev# mdadm --detail --scan
```

mdadm --assemble --scan --verbose shows:

```
/dev/sdc:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :   4294967295 sectors at            1 (type ee)
root@server:/dev# mdadm --examine /dev/sdd
/dev/sdd:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :   3907029167 sectors at            1 (type ee)
root@server:/dev# mdadm --examine /dev/sde
/dev/sde:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :   3907029167 sectors at            1 (type ee)
root@server:/dev# mdadm --examine /dev/sdf
/dev/sdf:
   MBR Magic : aa55
Partition[0] :   3907029167 sectors at            1 (type ee)
root@server:/dev# mdadm --detail --scan
```

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 2.73 TiB, 3000592982016 bytes, 5860533168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD30EZRX-00M
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 46FF8DF1-6613-474B-A513-FEB737C14B77
```

```
Disk /dev/sdd: 1.82 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk model: ST2000DM001-1CH1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 5BD6C09B-47DA-4BBD-9E85-46A43FF9610E
```

```
Disk /dev/sde: 1.82 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD20EARS-00M
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: D8822B21-1E1E-4F1B-9A49-9B2A0A76C48A
```

```
Disk /dev/sdf: 1.82 TiB, 2000398934016 bytes, 3907029168 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD20EARS-00M
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: EDA76DF6-EF1F-4D48-ABF1-70E253D26B10
```

Thoughts?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Was it running both mdadm RAID _and_ Intel hardware RAID?

Comment: `fdisk -l /dev/sd?` please. All in the question. At a guess your RAID was running in a full-disk partition rather than the disk itself

Comment: Updated @roaima

Comment: No, it was not running mdadm and Intel. I hadn't installed mdadm yet.

Comment: Ok looks like you've an older version of fdisk. Please replace its output with that of `for f in /dev/sd?; do parted "$f" --align optimal unit MiB print; done`

Comment: I'm on the current version of fdisk, 2.37.2.